# What difference do trans and cis configurations of amide groups bring to the polypeptide chain?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, amino-acids, protein-structure

Hi I was just wondering whether there would be any difference to the structure of the polypeptide chain, or any changes to a proteins characteristics, if it has more amide groups with a cis or trans configuration.

Apparently the trans configuration is more stable, so more amino acids with a trans configuration can be found within a polypeptide chain. Does this pose any significant characteristic to a protein, and if so what is this characteristic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Apparently the trans configuration is more stable, so more amino acids
>   with a trans configuration can be found within a polypeptide chain.
>   Does this pose any significant characteristic to a protein, and if so
>   what is this characteristic?

As you said, the *trans-* form is energetically more favourable. However, in proline the *cis-* form is energetically similar to the *trans-* form. The *cis-* structure introduces a kink or bend in the peptide chain which is seen in case of proline (see [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proline#Cis-trans_isomerization) of wikipedia page on proline).